# Como carregar uma imagem através do caminho dela armazenado no banco de dados?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Eu exportei um banco de dados de um site aqui da empresa onde eu trabalho, e importei esse mesmo banco de dados em um servidor xampp, em uma das tabelas do banco tem uma coluna imagem que é um campo varchar que contém o caminho de onde as imagens estão. A questão é, como eu posso carregar essas imagens no meu servidor local ? eu peguei as imagens do site e coloquei em uma pasta dentro do meu projeto no htdocs, mas mesmo assim não aparece nada.

A tabela no phpmyadmin ta assim

- nome - Geladeira
- valor - 10000
- observacao - Geladeira Brastemp Duas Portas, cor cinza prateada...
- data - 2019-03-31
- image - catalog/gel.jpg (varchar)

quando eu abro o site no localhost ele aparece só catalog/gel.jpg ao invés de aparecer a imagem, como eu posso resolver isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está colocando dentro do atributo `src` de uma tag `img`? Se sim, então você tem que se atentar no caminho de onde o arquivo do código está, e o da imagem.

Comment: eu to fazendo a query no banco de dados com php , assim, <?php echo $consulta['image'] ?>

Comment: quando eu passo isso dentro do src da tag img ele ta aparecendo apenas o valor do alt

Comment: <?php echo "<img src='../image/".$consulta['image']."' />"?> deu certo desse jeito

Comment: então o problema era apenas o caminho como eu tinha enunciado na resposta, perfeito.